# Linux Sockets bind connection

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I am trying to do a chatroom where I have a server and multi clients, but I have a problem, when I execute my code of server (serverCHAT.c), I have a problem with the bind connection. I don't know why.

When I execute the program, the if sentence of a bind problems appears on the console.

I check the connection, but I can not find the error.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_CLIENT 10

/*
BIBLIOGRAFIA:

https://github.com/yorickdewid/Chat-Server

comando linux ip: ifconfig  es : inet addr
*/



int totcltes=0;
int client_sockfd[MAX_CLIENT];
void *coneccion_clte(void *arg);
int clientes_conectados[MAX_CLIENT];

static unsigned int cli_count = 0;
static int uid = 10;


/* Cliente */
typedef struct {
    struct sockaddr_in addr;    /* Client remote address */
    int connfd;                 /* Connection file descriptor */
    int uid;                    /* Client unique identifier */
    char name[32];              /* Client name */
} client_t;

client_t *clients[MAX_CLIENT];


/* agregar cliente a la cola */
void queue_add(client_t *cl){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<MAX_CLIENT;i++){
        if(!clients[i]){
            clients[i] = cl;
            return;
        }// if 
    }// for
}// agregar cliente

/* quitar cliente de la cola */
void queue_delete(int uid){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<MAX_CLIENT;i++){
        if(clients[i]){
            if(clients[i]->uid == uid){
                clients[i] = NULL;
                return;
            }// if 
        }// if
    }// for 
}// quitar cola 

/* Senviar mensaje  */
void enviar_mensaje(char *s){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<MAX_CLIENT;i++){
        if(clients[i]){
            write(clients[i]->connfd, s, strlen(s));
        }// if 
    }// for 
}// enviar mensaje 



/* Handle all communication with the client */
void *coneccion_clte(void *arg){
    char buff_out[1024];// mensaje de salida
    char buff_in[1024]; // mensaje de entrada
    int rlen;           // longitu del mensaje

    cli_count++;        //aumentamos en uno el cliente 
    client_t *cli = (client_t *)arg;

    printf("Cliente Aceptado %d ", cli->uid);


    /* Recibiendo mensaje  */
    while((rlen = read(cli->connfd, buff_in, sizeof(buff_in)-1)) > 0){
            buff_in[rlen] = '\0';
            buff_out[0] = '\0';


        /* Special options */
        if(strncmp("exit",buff_in,4==0)){
            break;
        }else{
            sprintf(buff_out, "[%s]: %s\n", cli->name, buff_in);
            enviar_mensaje(buff_out);
        }//else
    }//while

    /* Cerrar al conexion */
    close(cli->connfd);

    /* Delete client from queue and yeild thread */
    queue_delete(cli->uid);
    printf("Fin del chat :c ");
    free(cli);
    cli_count--;
    //pthread_detach(pthread_self());
    return NULL;
}//coneccion_clte





int main()
{
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct sockaddr_in cli_addr;
    int server_sockfd ;// listenfd
    //int listenfd = 0; 
    int server_len, client_len;
    struct sockaddr_in server_address;
    struct sockaddr_in client_address;
    //int parametro[MAX_CLIENT];
    //pthread_t tid[MAX_CLIENT];
    //int i;
    pthread_t tid;
    int connfd = 0; //para obtener el descriptor de archivo (connection file descriptor y saber que hilo es)



    /* configuracion del socket*/
    server_sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    //listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    server_address.sin_port = htons(9734);
    server_len = sizeof(server_address);

    /*
    bind()
    Avisa al SO que hemos abierto un socket y asociamos nuestro programa a este socket 
    */
        //bind(server_sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&server_address,server_len);

    if(bind(server_sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_address,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0);{
        printf("Error: bind \n");
        //return 1;
    }//if bind 

    /* 
    Crear una cola de conexiones
    Listen 
    Indicamos al programa que empiece a escuchar peticiones y las registre
    */
    if(listen(server_sockfd, 5) < 0){
        printf("Error: Listen");
        //return 1;
    }//is listen


    printf("<[Servidor Inicializado :D]>\n");


    /* Aceptar clientes */
    while(totcltes<MAX_CLIENT){
        connfd = accept(server_sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&client_address, &client_len);

        /* Revisar el Total de clientes */
        if((cli_count+1) == MAX_CLIENT){
            printf("Clientes Maximos Alcanzados \n");
            close(connfd);
            continue;// para que revise la siguiente iteracion 
        }// if

        /* Configuracion del cliente */
        client_t *cli = (client_t *)malloc(sizeof(client_t));// creamos la estructura cliente cli
        cli->addr = client_address;
        cli->connfd = connfd;
        cli->uid = uid++;
        sprintf(cli->name, "%d", cli->uid);

        /* Agregar clientes a la cola */
        queue_add(cli);
        pthread_create(&tid, NULL, &coneccion_clte, (void*)cli);

    }//while aceptar clientes 
}//main
```

Comment: what is value of errno after error?

Comment: 'The if sentence of a bind problems appears on the console' is meaningless, as is 'I check the connection', as you don't have a connection if you got a bind problem. Please provide the *actual* error message or `errno`, and the line of code which caused it. You need to use `perror()` for that, not just `printf()` of some message of your own devising. And if you get an error from a system call, don't just continue as though it didn't happen.

Comment: Is something else using that port?

Comment: @Pras , in console appear the prinft in the validation (ERROR: Bind), and latter  show me the    "<[Servidor Inicializado :D]>\n"

Comment: @EdHeal , yes, on my client connection I put the same port

Comment: @EJP , I change the printf by perro and appears me: Error: bind : Success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You are using `sizeof(serv_addr)` as the length specifier instead of `server_len`.
2. You are declaring `server_len` as an `int`: it should be `socklen_t`.
3. You are doing the same thing with `client_len`: it should be `socklen_t`.

Please go back and study the original code from githu. It *actually* works.

Comment: I did the changes that you said me and also chechk the code , but the problem persist , I am going to try do the bind in the same form that github code to see if found it.

Comment: I did more corrections , after of take a break and walk, I came back and debbuging the code and also I compare my version with the version of github and I watched others errors, so now the server is working !!!, only I have another bug sending the mensage of all clients , until the client press enter the mensage appear, but I am going to check it, thank you a lot !